# settimeout, delay, setinterval

Tags: css, jquery, функции

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Мне необходимо через одинаковые промежутки времени вызвать одну и туже функцию.
Точнее.
Есть 7 элементов у которых нужно изменять стиль каждые 2 секунды. Т.е. добавляем стиль "active" через 2 секунды убираем его и вызываем эту же функцию, но она уже обращается к следующему элементу и делает тоже самое.
Итого 7 элементов.
Подскажите, как лучше сделать и оформить интервальные вызовы?
Для общего понимания, должна получиться новогодняя гирлянда с мигающими огоньками.

Сейчас примерно выглядит так

```
  function change (el) {

        el.addClass('active');
        setTimeout(
            function () {

                el.removeClass('active');
            }, 1000);
    }

start.on('click', function () {
change(circleOne);
change(circleTwo);
});
```

И пока ничего толком не получается)
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно как-нибудь так:

```js
next(document.getElementById('items').children, 0);

function next(items, cur) {
  items[cur % items.length].classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    items[cur % items.length].classList.remove('active');
    next(items, cur + 1)
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
#items div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  background-color: green !important
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```